# A vector for different classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a class with a vector I'd like to fill with one of two types of class, selected by the user. Let's call my classes option1 and option2

What I'd like to do it something like

```
class storage_class 
{
public:
    storage_class(int sel, int n)
    {
        if(sel == 1)
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
               my_store.push_back(std::make_unique<option1>());    
        else if(sel == 2)
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
               my_store.push_back(std::make_unique<option2>());
    }

private:
    // Something like this but that actually works
    std::vector<T> my_store;
};
```

Then I'd like to use it like this, or something similar, so there's no need to modify this usage dependent on the option chosen.

```
int main()
{
    storage_class store(1);

    int n_iterations = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_iterations; i++)
    {
        store.my_store[i]->create_data();
    }
}
```

The classes option1 and option2 will be mathematical simulations that will be creating data and themselves store this data in a vector that are members of the class.

I want to store multiple instances of either option in a vector and then manipulate them from there. I can use C++17.

Comment: What specific version of C++ are you using?

Comment: What information can you tell us about `option1` and `option2`? Are they two completely unrelated types? Must they be created on the heap for some reason (and why)? Are they both derived from some common `base`?

Comment: I have access to GCC 8 so can use modern C++ but realise my code is a bit of a mix.

Comment: @Justin Yes I can use C++17. option1 and option2 are classes that will produce large amounts of data (to be stored in vectors within the object (by this I mean the option1 or option2 class itself). I need to create any number of these and want to be able to access the data they create

Comment: @JackEvans -- Need more information.  Justin asked the pertinent questions.

Comment: With C++17 available, have a look at std::variant (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: If all you want is call a single member function on each of your option objects, just push an std::function instead.

Comment: And what with the obsession with std::option? Inheritance-based polymothism works better, maybe not every time, but this time definitely.

Comment: For a second I wondered about `std::vector<std::any>`, but it wouldn't work in this case because the contained object must be copy-constructible and `std::unique_ptr` is move-only.

Comment: why not just give storage_class a template parameter?

Comment: @Thomas could you write a quick answer to show what you mean?

Comment: @JackEvans ok, done. hope you find it useful.

Comment: @JackEvans If you need to change dynamically, you can also use `std::variant`. I've added a variant for that to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that tries to stay as close to your example as it can using a template parameter on class `storage_class`. See working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78dee920eca21d1a). I've added only `option1` and made the member `my_store` public as you access it in your `main` function.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct option1{
    void create_data(){ std::cout << "created\n"; }
};


template<typename T>
class storage_class 
{
public:
    storage_class(int n)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
           my_store.push_back(std::make_unique<T>());    
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> my_store;
};

int main()
{
    storage_class<option1> store(4);

    int n_iterations = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_iterations; i++)
    {
        store.my_store[i]->create_data();
    }
}
```

another option would be to use `std::variant`. See workign version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/773d85bafb7d2f6e).

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

struct option1{
    void create_data(){ std::cout << "created 1\n"; }
};

struct option2{
    void create_data(){ std::cout << "created 2\n"; }
};


class storage_class 
{
public:

    using option = std::variant<std::unique_ptr<option1>,std::unique_ptr<option2>>;

    storage_class(int sel, int n)
    {
        if(sel == 0)
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
               my_store.push_back(option(std::make_unique<option1>()));    
        else if(sel == 1)
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
               my_store.push_back(option(std::make_unique<option2>()));
    }


    std::vector<option> my_store;
};

int main()
{
    storage_class store(1, 4);

    int n_iterations = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_iterations; i++)
    {
        std::get<1>(store.my_store[i])->create_data();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you have c++17 in use, you can simply use a `std::variant` as type for the container which itself can keep all types you want to have.

Example:

```
class A { public: void Do() { std::cout << "A::Do" << std::endl; } };
class B { public: void Go() { std::cout << "B::Go" << std::endl; } };


template<class... Ts> struct funcs : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> funcs(Ts...) -> funcs<Ts...>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::variant<A,B>> vec;
    vec.push_back(A{});
    vec.push_back(B{});

    for ( auto& el: vec)
    {
        std::visit( funcs{ [](A& a){ a.Do(); }, [](B& b) { b.Go(); } }, el);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A::Do
B::Go
```

The classes are fully independent and the methods can be simply called with `std::visit` and passing a callable object herein. I provide a simple `funcs` implementation, which simply collect all callable entities to simplify to interface the call to different methods of different unrelated classes here.

As `std::variant` is some kind of a tagged union, it needs the storage for the biggest type you have in use. If this wastes to much memory, you can store a pointer to the instance instead, maybe with `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` if you like some assistance for memory management ;)

Comment: a cutting edge solution, nice

Comment: @neonxc: :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Standard way is to make `option1` and `option2` derived classes from a `base_class` which seems consistent with your sample `main()`. Using a generic `Factory` class template, here is an example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

// Generic Factory class template
template<typename K,typename T,typename... Ts>
class Factory
{
    using Map = std::unordered_map<K, std::function<std::unique_ptr<T>(Ts...)>>;
    const Map mMap;
  public:
    Factory(Map&& map):mMap(std::move(map)) { }
    std::unique_ptr<T> operator()(const K& key, Ts... args) const
    {
        const typename Map::const_iterator itr = mMap.find(key);
        return itr == mMap.cend() ? nullptr : itr->second(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};

class base_class
{
  public:
    virtual void create_data() = 0;
};

class option1 : public base_class
{
  public:
    void create_data() override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm option1." << std::endl;
    }
};

class option2 : public base_class
{
  public:
    void create_data() override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm option2." << std::endl;
    }
};

class storage_class 
{
    using SimulationFactory = Factory<int,base_class>; // Optionally add constructor parameter types
    const SimulationFactory simulation_factory; // This can be made static const.
public:
    storage_class(int sel, int n)
    :   simulation_factory(
            { { 1, []() { return std::make_unique<option1>(); } }
            , { 2, []() { return std::make_unique<option2>(); } }
            })
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            my_store.push_back(simulation_factory(sel));
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base_class>> my_store;
};

int main()
{
    int n_iterations = 4;

    storage_class store(1, n_iterations);

    for(int i = 0; i < n_iterations; i++)
    {
        store.my_store[i]->create_data();
    }
}
```

This compiled for me on linux using `g++ -std=c++17 main.cc`.

There are improvements that can be made to this code, but I copied your `main()` function in order to illustrate the basic idea(s). Hope that helps.

---

#### Edit 21 Sept 2018 - Example of how to pass parameters into constructors.

File: factory.h

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

// Generic Factory class template
template<typename K,typename T,typename... Ts>
class Factory
{
    using Map = std::unordered_map<K, std::function<std::unique_ptr<T>(Ts...)>>;
    const Map mMap;
  public:
    Factory(Map&& map):mMap(std::move(map)) { }
    std::unique_ptr<T> operator()(const K& key, Ts... args) const
    {
        const typename Map::const_iterator itr = mMap.find(key);
        return itr == mMap.cend() ? nullptr : itr->second(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};
```

File: main.cc

```
#include "factory.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class base_class
{
  public:
    virtual void create_data() = 0;
};

class option1 : public base_class
{
    const double mD;
  public:
    option1(double d)
    :   mD(d)
    { }
    void create_data() override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm option1: mD("<<mD<<')' << std::endl;
    }
};

class option2 : public base_class
{
    const double mD;
  public:
    option2(double d)
    :   mD(d)
    { }
    void create_data() override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm option2: mD("<<mD<<')' << std::endl;
    }
};

class storage_class 
{
    using SimulationFactory = Factory<int,base_class,double>; // Optionally add constructor parameter types
    const SimulationFactory simulation_factory; // This can be made static const.
public:
    storage_class(int sel, int n)
    :   simulation_factory(
            { { 1, [](double d) { return std::make_unique<option1>(d); } }
            , { 2, [](double d) { return std::make_unique<option2>(d); } }
            })
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            my_store.push_back(simulation_factory(sel,static_cast<double>(i)));
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base_class>> my_store;
};

int main()
{
    int n_iterations = 4;

    storage_class store1(1, n_iterations);
    storage_class store2(2, n_iterations);

    for(int i = 0; i < n_iterations; i++)
    {
        store1.my_store[i]->create_data();
        store2.my_store[i]->create_data();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I'm option1: mD(0)
I'm option2: mD(0)
I'm option1: mD(1)
I'm option2: mD(1)
I'm option1: mD(2)
I'm option2: mD(2)
I'm option1: mD(3)
I'm option2: mD(3)
```

Comment: With this method how can I pass into the constructors of my option classes?

Comment: An example was added for passing in a single `double` to the constructors, but you can add any number of parameters.

Comment: Great. Which solution best fits your needs, and why?